# Telerik Test Studio - Run this test button is disabled

Tags: telerik, telerik-test-studio

I have downloaded the latest test studio from Telerik website.

I have created a test based on the Sample tests (Load Tests) shipped with telerik. However, When I am trying to run the test I get this error "We are unable to run the tests. Please make sure that the controller that you are using have enough users allocated..." . Also the Run this test button is disabled. So I canNot run the test.

I tried to record a new test and still same result.

Does anyone knows what is this issue. I am following the guide on this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ekx7hjtDSbM&feature=c4-overview&list=UUSTKUvLyGUg-TIuN5qW48ZA

Does anyone know what this error is?

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to do the following to make it work:

Click on **manage** icon.
Then on **Add Scheduling Service**.
Type in the **Computer Name/IP**, test connection and click ok.
Drag the slider in the balance column to set the number of users and save settings.

Comment: i needed to change in programs to add the scheduling feature

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy. First you need to configure your controller.

1.Click on 'Manage' button.

2.'Manage Users' window will opens.

3.Click on 'Add Scheduling Service' button.

4.'Add Scheduling Service' window will opens.

5.Enter your 'Computer Name/IP'.(How to find name of your computer :http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/find-computer-name#1TC=windows-7).

6.Click on 'Test Connection'.

7.If you enter correct 'Computer Name/IP' then success message will appear 'Great! We were able to connect to that Scheduling Service'

8.Click 'Ok'

9.Finally 'Save'.

You can see that 'Run Test' will get enable. :)